# LINQ ".Include" orderby in subquery

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have the following entity code, which returns all users and "includes" all of their sample requests:

```
    var userQuery = from u in _IntranetContext.UserSet.Include("SampleRequests")
                           orderby u.LastName ascending
                           select u;
```

Each user has multiple SampleRequests. Each SampleRequest has an ID# (just an integer: 1, 22, 341, etc). The above LINQ to entities grabs the users and their SampleRequests like so:

User1: 33, 22, 341, 12

User2: 24, 3, 981

As you can see the SampleRequest ID# are not in an ascending order. I would like the results to be in order.

How do I put the orderby constraint on the Included SampleRequests ID#

Please note: SampleRequestId is a property of the SampleRequest...not a property of the User object

Comment: Had the same issue. Found... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304556/linq-orderby-name-thenby-childrencollection-name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304556/linq-orderby-name-thenby-childrencollection-name)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can currently think of two options for what you want. You can select them into a new class, where the user and the associated requests are properties:

```
var userQuery = from u in _IntranetContext.UserSet.Include("SampleRequests")
                orderby u.LastName ascending
                select new
                {
                    User = u,
                    SampleRequests = u.SampleRequests.OrderByDescending(r => r.SampleRequestId)
                };
```

This will cause issues if you wanted to return this type, as it is anonymous.

You can also select this into a new user object, similar to this:

```
var userQuery = from u in _IntranetContext.UserSet.Include("SampleRequests")
                orderby u.LastName ascending
                select new User
                {
                    Property1 = u.Property1,
                    Property2 = u.Property2,
                    Property3 = u.Property3,
                    SampleRequests = u.SampleRequests.OrderByDescending(r => r.SampleRequestId).ToList()
                };
```

This will return a collection of User objects, but updating the objects in the database could cause issues.

Comment: If User is an EF entity, you cannot assign the result of your OrderByDescending().ToList() call (a List<SampleRequest>) to the SampleRequests property on User, since its type will be EntityCollection<SampleRequest>. Also, I'd be wary of manually assigning each property in the query; if you add a new property to User later down the track and forget to update all your queries, you'll get User instances without that property assigned to. IMO it could be a maintenance PITA.

Comment: I find this quite ugly if your User-class has very many properties. Will this subcollection.ToList() make a lot of transfer between business logic and sql-server? One solution could be just fetch SampleRequests without order and then sort them later in c#-code (=memory).

Comment: You should create one sorted database index to UserSet.LastName. And another to SampleRequests with (foreign-key to UserSet and SampleRequestId)

Answer (score -1):

Just add another ordering parameter to the orderby:

```
var userQuery = from u in _IntranetContext.UserSet.Include("SampleRequests")
                           orderby u.LastName ascending, 
                                   u.SampleRequestId descending
                           select u;
```

Comment: Thanks, but SampleRequestId is a property of the SampleRequests include, not of the User object.

Comment: @John: This is the only answer I see for what you described. I think we need more information first.

Comment: OK i rewrote my question - i think it might be a bit more clear

Answer (score -2):

Edit: Treed by <15 seconds.

```
var userQuery = from u in _IntranetContext.UserSet.Include("SampleRequests")
                orderby u.LastName ascending, u.SampleRequestId descending
                select u;
```

Comment: Thanks, but SampleRequestId is a property of the SampleRequests include, not of the User object.